# Parsing HTML to text with link-tags remaining in R

Tags: html, r, xml, xpath

### My problem

I am trying to parse a HTML file (downloaded via Google Drive API as `text/html`) to a list in R.

The HTML looks like this (sorry for the German content):

```
<p style='padding:0;margin:0;color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-
family:"Arial";line-height:1.15;orphans:2;widows:2;text-align:left'>
<span>text: Das </span>
<span style="color:#1155cc;text-decoration:underline"><a 
href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/SharedDocs/Entscheidungen/DE/2011/10/rs20111012_2bvr023608.html&amp;sa=D&amp;ust=1503574789125000&amp;usg=AFQ
jCNE4Ij3mvMX-QttYQYqspAaMxaZaeg" style="color:inherit;text-
decoration:inherit">Verfassungsgericht urteilt</a></span>
<span style='color:#000000;font-weight:400;text-
decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;font-size:11pt;font-
family:"Arial";font-style:normal'>, 
dass eindeutig private Kommunikation von der Überwachung ausgenommen 
sein muss</span></p>
```

It works well when I just try to extract the text from the xmlValues (XML-library) by using something like:

```
doc <- htmlParse(html, asText = TRUE)
text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//text()", xmlValue)
```

But in my case, I need to retain the links (`<a>`-tags) in the HTML file, and delete the `https://www.google.com/url?q=`-part. So I want to get rid of all styling and keep only the text + the link-tags.

### What I tried so far

I tried to get both of the nodes by using `//(p | a)`in the XPath, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use the `rvest` package instead of `XML`.

In this code I use the rvest package to parse the html and extract out the links from the page.  Then using the `stringr` package I split the link text at the ?q= part and return the back half of the original link.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

#Read html file, 
page<-read_html("sample.txt") 

#then find the link nodes, then extract the attribute text (ie the links)
link<-page%>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr( "href")
#return second string of first list element 
#(Use sapply if there are more than 1 link in document)
desiredlink<-str_split(link, "\\?q=")[[1]][2]

#Find the text in all of the span nodes
span_text<-page%>% html_nodes("span") %>% html_text()
# or this for the text under the p nodes
p_text<-page%>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text()
```

I have your sample html code from above saved to the file: "sample.txt"

Comment: Hey Dave2e, thanks for your answer. That helps me to get the link without the google-part. But I still need some trick to get all the text from the complete html, right?

Comment: @BenedictWitzenberger, see edits above.  Either the span_text or p_text should contain the additional information you are looking for.